# SQL Subquery Exercises: Display the salesmen which name are alphabetically lower than the name of the customers

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This is the question on w3resource:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/subqueries/sql-subqueries-inventory-exercise-21.php

You can see the content of the table on the link above.
This is my solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM SALESMAN S WHERE S.SALESMAN_ID IN
                (
                    SELECT C.SALESMAN_ID
                    FROM CUSTOMER C
                    WHERE S.NAME < C.CUST_NAME
                );
```

And I recieved only one salemen named Jame Hoog. 
This is the website's solution:

```
SELECT *  
FROM salesman a  
WHERE EXISTS  
   (SELECT *  
    FROM CUSTOMER b  
    WHERE  a.name  < b.cust_name);
```

I don't really understand  why do they use EXISTS and I think my solution logically is still the same as their solution. Please tell me what's wrong with my solution. Please

Comment: Why not ask them?

Comment: Is `SALESMAN_ID` a join column between the two tables?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Yes, it is

Comment: The website's answer doesn't really seem right. It fetches all those salesmen where there exists any customer that is alphabetically after the salesman.

Comment: Indeed, you only [get one record back](http://rextester.com/NPRH86317).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries are not the same, as I will explain.  There is nothing wrong with your query or your single record result set, as this demo shows:

## Rextester

This query is finding every salesman which has at least one customer whose name is lexicographically greater than his own.  Only salesman James Hoog has a name which is lexicographically less than any of his customers.

On the other hand, the query from the website is looking for salesman names which are lexicographically less than *any* customer (either his own *or* someone else's) from each record in the `Salesman` table.  This is a much more lax requirement than what is used in your query.  The logic here is to retain any salesman for which there exist any customers whose name is greater than that of the salesman.  Only Pit Alex and Paul Adam fail to meet this requirement, there being no customers whose last name begin with the letter 'P' or any letter greater than that.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the problem. Can I change my query into that: `SELECT *
FROM SALESMAN  WHERE NAME< ANY
                    (
                        SELECT CUST_NAME
                        FROM CUSTOMER C
                    );`

Comment: Yes, this should match the query from the website, from a quick glance.  You can test this query using the demo link I gave you.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Your help is very valuable to me.